# Where to find Shopify API Password?

Tags: python, shopify

I'm trying to get Shopify data with Python. I'm stuck making a request to the API because I'm doing something wrong, obviously..

The request url has to be like : https://{API_KEY}:{PASSWORD}@Shop-name/admin/api/2022-04/orders.json

[image: 1]

I used the access token instead but it gives me a 401 error.

Can someone  help?

Comment: I believe it's the Admin API Access Token. Reveal the token, but make sure you copy it somewhere safe as it's unlikely that it will show you a second time if you lose it. Grain of salt though, I'm not a shopify expert. It's been years since I used their platform.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying HTTPBasicAuth that were allowed in `private apps` before in shopify. But you are using `custom apps`. So the setup a bit different now.

You need to reveal the admin access token and store it somewhere and later on you need to use that token in the request headers.

Try this code in python

```py
import requests

# Credential and endpoint
admin_access_token = "YOUR_REVEALED_ADMIN_ACCESS_TOKEN"
endpoint = "https://SHOP_NAME.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-04/orders.json"

# Set session header
session = requests.Session()
session.headers = {
                "X-Shopify-Access-Token": admin_access_token,
                "Content-Type": "application/json" }

response = session.get(endpoint)

orders = response.json()
```

Comment: Good God I have been trying to find an answer to how to use the Shopify Python API for ages. Thank you so much. This answer should be on the docs....

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems to authenticate with the Shopify API using their Python library.

I managed to do it this way:

```
session = shopify.Session(f"{SHOPIFY_SHOP_NAME}.myshopify.com", version="2023-04", token=ADMIN_API_ACCESS_TOKEN)
shopify.ShopifyResource.activate_session(session)

# ... Do the stuff you want here, e.g. add a product, ...

shopify.ShopifyResource.clear_session()
```